# Slider with rslides rezising itself due to different size images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

When trying use the, otherwise brilliant, rslides js plugin I bump into this annoying problem. I want the images to be imported to the site via links which means I can't resize them but the slider handles this rather poorly; it expands. Now, the slider is responsive, it scales with the page width. One solution might be to set static values for the size but I would prefer not doing this as it would probably break the responsive %scaling.

Edit: forgot to link site http://208.69.30.150/build/age_past.html

Some clarification that's come up in the comments:

The images are resized within the slider. But the slider is resizing to some of the images sizes, only on the height, this is because the images do not all have the same aspect ratios. So I want to resize the images width, and if the height overflows I want to crop of that overflow.

CSS

```
/*SLIDER*/
.slider{
    background-color: #222;
}
.rslides_container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: 100%;
    background: #222;
}
    .slider .slider_medium{
        max-width: 900px;
    }
.rslides {
    border-radius:200px;
    -moz-border-radius:20px;
    -webkit-border-radius:20px;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.rslides li {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.rslides li:first-child {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.rslides img {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
}
/*SLIDER OVERLAY IMAGES*/
    #banner_image_1 img{
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 5;
        top: 10%;
        left: 3%;
        height:auto; 
        width:auto; 
        max-height: 100px; 
        background: #FFF;
    }
    #banner_image_2 img{
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 5;
        bottom: 3%;
        right: 1%;
        height: 20%;  
        max-height:60px;
    }
    #banner_image_3 img{
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 5;
        bottom: 3%;
        right: 7%;
        height: 20%;  
        max-height:60px;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="block slider">
              <div class="rslides_container slider_medium">
                <!--<a id="banner_image_1" href="" target="">
                  <img src="">
                </a>-->
                <ul class="rslides">
                  <li>
                    <a href="http://www.agepast.com/">
                      <img src="http://fc00.deviantart.net/fs70/i/2010/194/2/5/Age_Past_Wallpaper_by_Tsabo6.jpg"/>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="http://www.agepast.com/">
                      <img src="http://fc03.deviantart.net/fs71/i/2011/211/c/6/age_past_by_tsabo6-d424m3v.jpg"/>
                    </a>
                  </li>  
                  <li>
                    <a href="http://www.agepast.com/">
                      <img src="http://fc00.deviantart.net/fs70/i/2010/257/7/e/age_past_earth_magic_by_tsabo6-d2yp0v0.jpg"/>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="http://www.agepast.com/">
                      <img src="http://fc01.deviantart.net/fs71/i/2010/244/8/2/age_past_wall_2_by_tsabo6-d2xr9g0.jpg"/>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
                <script>
                  $(function() {
                    $(".rslides").responsiveSlides({
                      auto: true, speed: 1500, timeout: 5000, pause: true,
                    });
                  });
                </script>
            </div>
```

& LOTS of JS (which just won't be formatted right.)

```
(function ($, window, i) {
```

$.fn.responsiveSlides = function (options) {

```
// Default settings
var settings = $.extend({
  "auto": true,             // Boolean: Animate automatically, true or false
  "speed": 500,             // Integer: Speed of the transition, in milliseconds
  "timeout": 4000,          // Integer: Time between slide transitions, in milliseconds
  "pager": false,           // Boolean: Show pager, true or false
  "nav": false,             // Boolean: Show navigation, true or false
  "random": false,          // Boolean: Randomize the order of the slides, true or false
  "pause": false,           // Boolean: Pause on hover, true or false
  "pauseControls": true,    // Boolean: Pause when hovering controls, true or false
  "prevText": "Previous",   // String: Text for the "previous" button
  "nextText": "Next",       // String: Text for the "next" button
  "maxwidth": "",           // Integer: Max-width of the slideshow, in pixels
  "navContainer": "",       // Selector: Where auto generated controls should be appended to, default is after the <ul>
  "manualControls": "",     // Selector: Declare custom pager navigation
  "namespace": "rslides",   // String: change the default namespace used
  "before": $.noop,         // Function: Before callback
  "after": $.noop           // Function: After callback
}, options);

return this.each(function () {

  // Index for namespacing
  i++;

  var $this = $(this),

    // Local variables
    vendor,
    selectTab,
    startCycle,
    restartCycle,
    rotate,
    $tabs,

    // Helpers
    index = 0,
    $slide = $this.children(),
    length = $slide.size(),
    fadeTime = parseFloat(settings.speed),
    waitTime = parseFloat(settings.timeout),
    maxw = parseFloat(settings.maxwidth),

    // Namespacing
    namespace = settings.namespace,
    namespaceIdx = namespace + i,

    // Classes
    navClass = namespace + "_nav " + namespaceIdx + "_nav",
    activeClass = namespace + "_here",
    visibleClass = namespaceIdx + "_on",
    slideClassPrefix = namespaceIdx + "_s",

    // Pager
    $pager = $("<ul class='" + namespace + "_tabs " + namespaceIdx + "_tabs' />"),

    // Styles for visible and hidden slides
    visible = {"float": "left", "position": "relative", "opacity": 1, "zIndex": 2},
    hidden = {"float": "none", "position": "absolute", "opacity": 0, "zIndex": 1},

    // Detect transition support
    supportsTransitions = (function () {
      var docBody = document.body || document.documentElement;
      var styles = docBody.style;
      var prop = "transition";
      if (typeof styles[prop] === "string") {
        return true;
      }
      // Tests for vendor specific prop
      vendor = ["Moz", "Webkit", "Khtml", "O", "ms"];
      prop = prop.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + prop.substr(1);
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < vendor.length; i++) {
        if (typeof styles[vendor[i] + prop] === "string") {
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    })(),

    // Fading animation
    slideTo = function (idx) {
      settings.before(idx);
      // If CSS3 transitions are supported
      if (supportsTransitions) {
        $slide
          .removeClass(visibleClass)
          .css(hidden)
          .eq(idx)
          .addClass(visibleClass)
          .css(visible);
        index = idx;
        setTimeout(function () {
          settings.after(idx);
        }, fadeTime);
      // If not, use jQuery fallback
      } else {
        $slide
          .stop()
          .fadeOut(fadeTime, function () {
            $(this)
              .removeClass(visibleClass)
              .css(hidden)
              .css("opacity", 1);
          })
          .eq(idx)
          .fadeIn(fadeTime, function () {
            $(this)
              .addClass(visibleClass)
              .css(visible);
            settings.after(idx);
            index = idx;
          });
      }
    };

  // Random order
  if (settings.random) {
    $slide.sort(function () {
      return (Math.round(Math.random()) - 0.5);
    });
    $this
      .empty()
      .append($slide);
  }

  // Add ID's to each slide
  $slide.each(function (i) {
    this.id = slideClassPrefix + i;
  });

  // Add max-width and classes
  $this.addClass(namespace + " " + namespaceIdx);
  if (options && options.maxwidth) {
    $this.css("max-width", maxw);
  }

  // Hide all slides, then show first one
  $slide
    .hide()
    .css(hidden)
    .eq(0)
    .addClass(visibleClass)
    .css(visible)
    .show();

  // CSS transitions
  if (supportsTransitions) {
    $slide
      .show()
      .css({
        // -ms prefix isn't needed as IE10 uses prefix free version
        "-webkit-transition": "opacity " + fadeTime + "ms ease-in-out",
        "-moz-transition": "opacity " + fadeTime + "ms ease-in-out",
        "-o-transition": "opacity " + fadeTime + "ms ease-in-out",
        "transition": "opacity " + fadeTime + "ms ease-in-out"
      });
  }

  // Only run if there's more than one slide
  if ($slide.size() > 1) {

    // Make sure the timeout is at least 100ms longer than the fade
    if (waitTime < fadeTime + 100) {
      return;
    }

    // Pager
    if (settings.pager && !settings.manualControls) {
      var tabMarkup = [];
      $slide.each(function (i) {
        var n = i + 1;
        tabMarkup +=
          "<li>" +
          "<a href='#' class='" + slideClassPrefix + n + "'>" + n + "</a>" +
          "</li>";
      });
      $pager.append(tabMarkup);

      // Inject pager
      if (options.navContainer) {
        $(settings.navContainer).append($pager);
      } else {
        $this.after($pager);
      }
    }

    // Manual pager controls
    if (settings.manualControls) {
      $pager = $(settings.manualControls);
      $pager.addClass(namespace + "_tabs " + namespaceIdx + "_tabs");
    }

    // Add pager slide class prefixes
    if (settings.pager || settings.manualControls) {
      $pager.find('li').each(function (i) {
        $(this).addClass(slideClassPrefix + (i + 1));
      });
    }

    // If we have a pager, we need to set up the selectTab function
    if (settings.pager || settings.manualControls) {
      $tabs = $pager.find('a');

      // Select pager item
      selectTab = function (idx) {
        $tabs
          .closest("li")
          .removeClass(activeClass)
          .eq(idx)
          .addClass(activeClass);
      };
    }

    // Auto cycle
    if (settings.auto) {

      startCycle = function () {
        rotate = setInterval(function () {

          // Clear the event queue
          $slide.stop(true, true);

          var idx = index + 1 < length ? index + 1 : 0;

          // Remove active state and set new if pager is set
          if (settings.pager || settings.manualControls) {
            selectTab(idx);
          }

          slideTo(idx);
        }, waitTime);
      };

      // Init cycle
      startCycle();
    }

    // Restarting cycle
    restartCycle = function () {
      if (settings.auto) {
        // Stop
        clearInterval(rotate);
        // Restart
        startCycle();
      }
    };

    // Pause on hover
    if (settings.pause) {
      $this.hover(function () {
        clearInterval(rotate);
      }, function () {
        restartCycle();
      });
    }

    // Pager click event handler
    if (settings.pager || settings.manualControls) {
      $tabs.bind("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (!settings.pauseControls) {
          restartCycle();
        }

        // Get index of clicked tab
        var idx = $tabs.index(this);

        // Break if element is already active or currently animated
        if (index === idx || $("." + visibleClass).queue('fx').length) {
          return;
        }

        // Remove active state from old tab and set new one
        selectTab(idx);

        // Do the animation
        slideTo(idx);
      })
        .eq(0)
        .closest("li")
        .addClass(activeClass);

      // Pause when hovering pager
      if (settings.pauseControls) {
        $tabs.hover(function () {
          clearInterval(rotate);
        }, function () {
          restartCycle();
        });
      }
    }

    // Navigation
    if (settings.nav) {
      var navMarkup =
        "<a href='#' class='" + navClass + " prev'>" + settings.prevText + "</a>" +
        "<a href='#' class='" + navClass + " next'>" + settings.nextText + "</a>";

      // Inject navigation
      if (options.navContainer) {
        $(settings.navContainer).append(navMarkup);
      } else {
        $this.after(navMarkup);
      }

      var $trigger = $("." + namespaceIdx + "_nav"),
        $prev = $trigger.filter(".prev");

      // Click event handler
      $trigger.bind("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $visibleClass = $("." + visibleClass);

        // Prevent clicking if currently animated
        if ($visibleClass.queue('fx').length) {
          return;
        }

        //  Adds active class during slide animation
        //  $(this)
        //    .addClass(namespace + "_active")
        //    .delay(fadeTime)
        //    .queue(function (next) {
        //      $(this).removeClass(namespace + "_active");
        //      next();
        //  });

        // Determine where to slide
        var idx = $slide.index($visibleClass),
          prevIdx = idx - 1,
          nextIdx = idx + 1 < length ? index + 1 : 0;

        // Go to slide
        slideTo($(this)[0] === $prev[0] ? prevIdx : nextIdx);
        if (settings.pager || settings.manualControls) {
          selectTab($(this)[0] === $prev[0] ? prevIdx : nextIdx);
        }

        if (!settings.pauseControls) {
          restartCycle();
        }
      });

      // Pause when hovering navigation
      if (settings.pauseControls) {
        $trigger.hover(function () {
          clearInterval(rotate);
        }, function () {
          restartCycle();
        });
      }
    }

  }

  // Max-width fallback
  if (typeof document.body.style.maxWidth === "undefined" && options.maxwidth) {
    var widthSupport = function () {
      $this.css("width", "100%");
      if ($this.width() > maxw) {
        $this.css("width", maxw);
      }
    };

    // Init fallback
    widthSupport();
    $(window).bind("resize", function () {
      widthSupport();
    });
  }

});
```

};
})(jQuery, this, 0);

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add `width: auto;` and `overflow: hidden` to your slider container

Comment: Done, under .rslides_container{}. Seemingly no effect. Will try using it in some other divs.

Edit: tried a couple of places, no luck. Please elaborate ^^.

Comment: @IthilonethMoonsnow is the slider resizing to image size or is the image getting stretched to slider's size

Comment: Both. The images are resized within the slider. But the slider is resizing to some of the images sizes, only on the height, this is because the images do not all have the same aspect ratios. So I want to resize the images width, and if the height overflows I want to crop of that overflow. In an optimal world that's how I'd like it anyway.

Comment: Edit: testing new answer :). Thank you!
Not sure if I answered your question right, I stretch the slider container width to 100% or 1000x, whichever is smaller. The images then take up 100% of that width. The problem here is that the relative width/height values (aspect ratios) of the images are not all the same. So while the width remains the same the height changes.

Comment: @IthilonethMoonsnow wow , nice template , did u make it or did you take it from a website?

Comment: Nope, I once again added the values to the .rslides_container. No change. The slider goes: block{ rslides_container{ ul{ li{ a{ img}}}}} The template is bits and parts from all over. Most can be found here: http://callmenick.com

Comment: @IthilonethMoonsnow ahhh! its so hard to correct a bug, i have a good working slider can i just provide you the code to help you out?

Comment: Sure, I don't mind switching things around. Should we open a chat somewhere? The help notification keeps telling me not to prolong the discussion.

Comment: Ok let me end it here , just use this http://cssslider.com/ , peace out! I cant help you out anymore , SORRY!

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a proper solution. I solved my issue by switching slider. If anyone finds an answer please do share, meanwhile I suggest trying this: http://www.builtbyevolve.com/work/plugins/nerve-slider